# Why I don't have a /usr/lib/systemd/system folder?

Tags: systemd, services

I am trying to use `systemd` for the first time after giving up on `supervisord`.

Following this documentation for airflow [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd), my understanding is that I need to move the `.service` files to `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, however such directory does not exist in my system (`Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`). Instead I have `/usr/lib/systemd/system-environment-generators/`.

Should I create this `system` folder myself or have I made a mistake somewhere which I need to fix otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu the folder that holds the `.service` files is */lib/systemd/system*. This folder is intended to be used by `.deb` packages.

Best option to place `systemd` related files which are not provided by a Debian package would be */etc/systemd/system*.

Comment: So should I create this folder myself or it should already exist and I have messed something up?

Comment: */lib/systemd/system* and */etc/systemd/system* should exist already.

Comment: They both do, however `/usr/lib/systemd/system` does not (which is my question). Why is that?

Comment: Because in Ubuntu that path is */lib/systemd/system* and not */usr/lib/systemd/system*. No need to create any folder.

Comment: Okay so in this case why do I have a `/usr/lib/systemd` folder and in which folder should I be adding the `.service` files? Sorry, it's all very confusing.

Comment: Add your service to */etc/systemd/system*. That path is intended to place `systemd` files that are not provided by Debian packages. I cannot answer why Ubuntu did choose that path layout, but you also my want to read `man systemd`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess you mean the systemd manual (documentation)?

Comment: That is correct, try reading the manual (man) page for details. The airflow document you read might have been referred to non Ubuntu OS hence the confusion about systemd path.